# El swagger no me devuelve el objeto con todas sus relaciones C#

Tags: c#, sql, json, swagger

estoy haciendo una aplicación donde un Alumno tiene muchos Profesores y un Profesor tiene muchos Alumnos. Para ello he creado una clase que se llama AlumnoProfesor.

La clase alumno está de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase profesor está de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase AlumnoProfesor está de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el SQL server management studio me sale que la relación existe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el swagger en el GET, no me aparece el objeto con todas sus relaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que debo hacer o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: tengo el mismo problema; alguien tiene alguna respuesta? hace 2 dìas que intento entender lo que sucede pero no le encuentro la soluciòn; mil gracias si pueden ayudarme.
saludos
Daniel